# Is it possible to change the package being used at runtime?

Tags: java, javafx, package

I have a large application that I am working to expand upon to allow customized usage by other departments within my organization.

Each department has different needs but may share some of the same classes as-is but other must be modified to accommodate the department's specific needs.

What I am wanting to do is create a new package for each department and move the relevant classes under those packages, thus keeping them separated, but all contained within the same overall application.

Right now, my package structure is similar to this:

```
[src]
    - Main.java
    [view]
        - D1 FXMLs
    [controllers]
        - D1 Controllers
    [model]
        -D1 Classes
```

What I am hoping to do is restructure the project to include additional departments, many using the same class names as D1 (department 1).

```
[src]
    - Main.java
    [D1]
        [view]
            - D1 FXMLs
        [controllers]
            - D1 Controllers
        [model]
            -D1 Classes
    [D2]
        [view]
            - D2 FXMLs
        [controllers]
            - D2 Controllers
        [model]
            - D2 Classes
...etc
```

I would need my `Main.java` to determine which package the operate out of, based on the value of a variable at runtime.

Is this even possible or would I still need to create entirely separate projects for each department and have a "Loader" program determine which one to run?

**EDIT:** Perhaps I have just stumbled on the answer myself. Would it work to just have `Main.java` call a class within the D1 or D2 package and have *that* class properly assign the packages going forward?

Comment: Read up on factory patterns (particularly the abstract factory pattern).

Comment: An example from the JDK is the factory for url stream handling.  You can find the implementation here: [Factory implements URLStreamHandlerFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/misc/Launcher.java#Launcher.Factory).  That example uses reflection, which you may or may not want to use.  A hard-coded list of department names will also work if you know the names up-front at compile time.  The reflection is to allow for dynamic implementation choice at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While possibly not the most elegant solution, I used a simple approach (as my skill is not yet to the point where I understand Factories).

I just implemented what my edit to the question suggested, calling a different package's `RootLayoutController` depending on which package was needed.